# How to get a screen capture using CGDisplayStreamCreate

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, core-graphics

I want to get a next frame of screen capture using CGDisplayStreamCreate but i have no idea that how to get the data.
I tryed to this code:(Swift)

```
        let stream  = CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue(displayID, 100, 100,Int32(k32BGRAPixelFormat), nil, queue) { (status, code, iosurface, update) in

        switch(status){
        case .FrameBlank:
            print("FrameBlank")
            break;
        case .FrameIdle:
            print("FrameIdle")
            break;
        case .FrameComplete:
            print("FrameComplete")
            break;
        case .Stopped:
            print("Stopped")
            break;
        }

    }
    let error:CGError = CGDisplayStreamStart(stream)
```

The result is `FrameComplete`.so i think it was generated a new frame data.
How do i get a new frame data as CGImage?

Comment: Document is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue

Comment: Isn't that what the `iosurface` is for?

Comment: I searched about IOSurface but i couldn't understand how to use it.
Is it possible to extract image convertible something?

Comment: Looks like CIImage can do it.